# ASP.NET MVC Route Contraints with {ID}-{Slug} Format

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have a route like following, ideally I would like it to match:

domain.com/layout/1-slug-is-the-name-of-the-page

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Layout",                                                // Route name
            "layout/{id}-{slug}",                                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"}, new {id = @"\d+$"}
        );
```

But when I hit the url, I am keep on getting this exception:

The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(Int32)' in ....

The above route will match the following though:

domain.com/layout/1-slug or domain.com/layout/1-slug_permalink

Seems like the hyphen that separates the ID from the Slug is causing issues.

Comment: Can you use a slash instead? "layout/{id}/{slug}"

Comment: I would like to keep things simple and simulate a flatter site structure

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the first step of processing, the Routing module performs pattern matching of the incoming URL against the declared route.  This pattern matching is eager (so the *id* gets all hyphens up to the last one, which marks the beginning of the *slug* parameter).  Constraints (like "\d+") run after pattern matching.  So what's tripping you up is that the eager pattern matching is setting *id* to an invalid value, then it's failing the constraint, which causes the overall route not to match, so the pipeline moves on trying to match the incoming request to the next route in the collection.

The best (e.g. easiest to understand, non-trickery) way to work around this is to match the entire segment as an *idAndSlug* parameter, then use a proper regex within the controller to split this string back out into its *id* and *slug* constituents.

Alternatively, consider using the slash, as suggested by mxmissile.