# mvc2 - getting the URL to reflect the form submission

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, forms, url-rewriting, url-routing

I have an MVC2 application with a form (like ya do).  The user enters a query into the form (in the /Cars/Index view) and hits the "submit" button which posts to the *Details* action of CarsController - the Details view renders with results, and all is well and good.

The user can enter a URL (such as /Cars/Details/123-125) and they get the Details view with 123, 124 and 125 displayed, same as if you'd entered it on the form.  Also well and good.

What I want to enable, if possible, is that when the user enters "123-125" or whatever in the form the URL also reflects the results - instead of "/Cars/Details" for a URL, which is what shows now, I want it to show "/Cars/Details/123-125".

For the life of me, I cannot figure out how this should be done.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is the answer I came up with:

> In short: Redirect to GET

Basically, I write an action with [HttpPost] Attribute that redirects the form submittal to another action with [HttpGet] attribute.  The route works whether you submit the form or type in the URL manually.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Details(CarViewModel model, int? pageNbr) {
    // simply takes the form POST and re-routes it as a GET to pretty up the URL
    // (see second Details action)
        int page = pageNbr ?? 0;

        return RedirectToAction("Details", new { query = model.Query, pageNbr = page });
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Details(CarViewModel model, int pageNbr)
    {
        // various magic to create the view...

        return View(avm);
    }
```

As an added bonus, this takes care of the "Are you sure you want to resubmit?" annoyance when someone refreshes the page or hits the BACK button in their browser.

Answer (score 0):

Change your form to a `GET` instead of `POST` method (POST is the default), and it should just work.

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Get)) { %>
```

Comment: well, it was a step in the right direction - but the URL now looks like this, which is close but not quite: /Cars/Details?Query=123.  I'm looking for /Cars/Details/123

Comment: To get the URL to look like you want, you could add a new Route for that case. Are you familiar with adding routes? The path spec would be something like `/Cars/Details/{*Query}` and then set the Controller and Action defaults as appropriate.

Comment: I edited the above and added the asterisk in front of Query; you'd need that to be sure that the dash you suggested could be in the values does not cause routing to get confused and think you have two separate parameters.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like its not finding a matching route definition for /Cars/Details/123-125. I think this could be happening because of the way the routing engine works.

[ASP.NET MVC Route Contraints with {ID}-{Slug} Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568146/asp-net-mvc-route-contraints-with-id-slug-format)

Comment: I don't believe that is the case - if you type /Cars/Details/123-125 into the address bar and hit enter *it works*.  If you use the form it also works, but just has /Cars/Details/.  If the route weren't there it wouldn't work at all.

Comment: Hmmm... in your form, are you passing along the 123-125 in the RouteData?

Comment: what ScottSEA said; his Controller Action works fine, but the default for Forms is that they will submit via POST, but he wants it to do via GET so the query info is in the query string. Routing does have some involvement here though, because of how he wants the resulting URL to appear. (see comments on my answer)

Comment: I have had a similar issue getting a form to submit values using GET and formatting the URL based on the routing rules.